# Replace String with value `$&' not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string `show {{value}}` and I want  replace `{{value}}` with `$&` but it not work. It return current value `show {{value}}`.
Here is my code

```js
let data ="show {{value}}";
let output = data.replace("{{value}}","$&");
alert(output);
```

I don't know why it not work. I try replace with other strings same `$1`, `$a` and it work.
How I can fix my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ is a special symbol in javascript. Write $$& instead and it should work :)

Comment: More specifically, a special symbol in [replacement strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Comment: Yep, it worked. but only the case $& is not working, other case same $1, $a working, so i don't understand what causes the error